# how to import simplegui in vscode?

Tags: python, import

trying to run a application in python locally that uses simplegui library

what do I need to do to import simplegui in vscode?

I tried:

```
pip install SimpleGUICS2Pygame --user --upgrade
```

but got this error:

```
import simplegui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simplegui'
```

Comment: That package uses a different import.  `import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui`

Comment: py -m pip install SimpleGUICS2Pygame  --upgrade

Comment: import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui 

worked here for me

thanks